# unexpected operator [: git: in bourne shell script 'if' conditional statement

Tags: debugging, bash, shell, unix, sh

I've watched an excellent shell scripting course through a multitude of [videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NhViktT-w1o&feature=plcp). Now that I think I am fairly familiar with the Bourne shell, I decided to write my first shell script.

Script goal: check if git working directory is clean. If so, overwrite working directory to a branch named `deployment`. Finally, push the deployment branch to origin.

I ended up with this code:

```
#!/bin/sh

######################################################
# Deploys working directory to git deployment branch.
# Requires that the working directory is clean.
######################################################

#check if the working directory is clean
if [ git diff-index --quiet HEAD ]
then
    if [ git branch -f deployment ]
    then
        if [ git push origin deployment ]
        then
            echo
            echo "OK. Successfully deployed to git deployment branch."
            echo
            exit 0 #success
        else
            echo
            echo "Error: failed to push deployment branch to origin."
            echo
            exit 1 #failure
        fi
    else
        echo
        echo "Error: failed to create or overwrite deployment branch."
        echo
        exit 1 #failure
    fi
else
    echo
    git status #show the status of the working directory
    echo
    echo "Error: working directory is not clean. Commit your changes first..."
    echo
    exit 1 #failure
fi
```

Unfortunately, this seems to give me an error: `./tools/deploygit: 9: [: git: unexpected operator`

Why is this so? What operator am I using in `if [ git diff-index --quiet HEAD ]` that is unexpected?

As a bonus, do you have any suggestions or tips on how to improve the efficiency, logic or readability of this script?

Comment: In terms of logic, it would be easier to understand if you did something like: die() { echo "ERROR: $*" >&2; exit 1; }; git diff-index --quiet HEAD || die working directory not clean; git branch -f deployment || die failed to create or overwrite deployment branch ...

Comment: BTW -- which platform are you on? `/bin/sh` is POSIX sh, not Bourne, on almost every operating system built inside the last two decades, with Sun being the sole laggard. (Bash's name implies Bourne as its immediate predecessor, but that was a case of accuracy being sacrificed in favor of a good pun).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this statement:

```
if [ git diff-index --quiet HEAD ]
```

The `[` is an alias for the `test` command, so what you're actually running is...

```
if test git diff-index --quiet HEAD ]
```

...which isn't what you mean.  You don't need to use the `test` command in order to evaluate the result of a command; you should just do this:

```
if git diff-index --quiet HEAD
```

Take a look at the documentation for the `if` command:

```
$ help if
if: if COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; [ elif COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; ]... [ else COMMANDS; ] fi
```

The conditional argument to the `if` statement is *command*.  Normally, the `test` command is used to make it look like other languages, but you can put *any* command there.  Things that exit with a return code of 0 evaluate to true and anything else evaluates to false.

Comment: I can't believe I missed this. The videos explained very well that `[` is actually the test program. Thanks a lot.